# Python selenium slows down when returning through loop

Tags: python, selenium, xlrd

The scripts below read an excel sheet and find order numbers on the page; when one is found the script will enter the corresponding tracking number, return to the first page (which is the same page it originally searched) and continue looking through the order numbers.

Can anyone tell me why the following scripts slow down considerably when returning to that page? For instance: The scripts will work extremely well and searches about 5 order numbers a second and enters the tracking number and submits it very quick.

When the script goes back to the pages with the unshipped orders it takes VERY long to search for more of them (maybe 1 every MINUTE)

The "Not ups Tracking" and "Fedex" else functions does NOT get slow after completion (These are manually entered then the script is "restarted manually" by pressing enter)

The script looks like this:

```
    list_of_files = glob.glob('F:/TrackingBot/GC/updater/*')  # * means all if need specific format then *.csv
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(latest_file)
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
    for i in range(sheet.nrows):
        cell = sheet.cell(i, 3)
        cty = cell.ctype
        if cty == xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY:
            continue
        else:
            po = (sheet.cell_value(i, 3))
            tracking = (sheet.cell_value(i, 10))
            wayfair = "CS"
            wayfsubstring = wayfair in po
            if wayfsubstring == True:
                continue
            print("SEARCHING FOR: ", po)
            if driver.find_elements_by_link_text(po):
                print("FOUND!!!!", po, tracking)
                driver.find_element_by_link_text(po).click()
                ups = "1Z"
                isSubstring = ups in tracking
                if isSubstring == True:
                    cprint('UPS TRACKING NUMBER', 'green')
                    driver.implicitly_wait(25)
                    confirm = driver.find_element_by_link_text("""Confirm shipment""")
                    confirm.click()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    trackingnum = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//input[contains(@data-test-id,
                    'text-input-tracking-id')]""")
                    trackingnum.click()
                    trackingnum.send_keys(tracking)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""(//input[@value='Confirm shipment'])[2]""").click()
                    time.sleep(3)
                    driver.refresh()
                    time.sleep(4)
                    continue

                else:
                    cprint("NOT UPS TRACKING", "red")
                    period = "."
                    isSubstring2 = period in tracking
                    if isSubstring2 == True:
                        cprint('NJ SENT TRACKING NUMBER', 'yellow')
                        input("Type to GO")
                        driver.refresh()
                        time.sleep(4)
                        continue
                    else:
                        cprint('FEDEX FREIGHT TRACKING NUMBER', 'green')
                        input("Type to GO")
                        driver.refresh()
                        time.sleep(4)
                        continue
```

The code above is for Amazon

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: your waits are 25 seconds a piece... the one has 3 of them and the other 4.  3*25=75 seconds... use a WebDriverWait (with ExpectedCondition) instead... this will wait the minimum amount of time and throw timeout if the element was not found within the timeout period.  You won't need the sleeps either...

Comment: driver.implicitly_wait(25) , waits "up to" 25 seconds but it doesn't actually wait if the element is available. Like i said the first run is lightning fast

Comment: whoops mistook that for explicit wait because you set it so many times... you should only need to set that once, no?  You may want also want to catch some exceptions to see if it is taking longer than 25 seconds to find any of these elements.  I would remove the sleeps and extra implicit waits...  sleeping the thread and resetting it's timeout while it is re-trying every 1/2 second seems like a bad idea.

Comment: hmm, i thought I tried that but i'll try it again, thanks. The part it hangs up on is if driver.find_elements_by_link_text(po): AFTER it goes through the initial loop

Comment: Also, i'm not sure why i was using implicitly_wait multiple times either now that i'm thinking of it

Comment: not familiar with python, but maybe it's not finding a bunch of them and the multiple refreshes are taking a while.  The driver will wait for the page to load before continuing.

Comment: what may be better is to find the full list of elements you are trying to search through.  That way you check once and get a List<WebElement> back.  You can then loop through those values to check against your po list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem, it was due to an implicitly wait.

The code snippet below shows where I initially set the wait.

```
            if isSubstring == True:
                cprint('UPS TRACKING NUMBER', 'green')
                driver.implicitly_wait(25)
                confirm = driver.find_element_by_link_text("""Confirm shipment""")
                confirm.click()
```

The problem with that is the driver kept that wait time when going back through the loop so when the thread got back to:

```
        print("SEARCHING FOR: ", po)
        if driver.find_elements_by_link_text(po):
            print("FOUND!!!!", po, tracking)
```

It waited for the max 25 second time before moving onto the next order number in the excel sheet. I fixed this by recalling another implicitly wait right before the loop searched for another order number. This way the wait needed later in the loop doesn't affect the searching as seen below:

```
    print("SEARCHING FOR: ", po)
    driver.implicitly_wait(.5)
    if driver.find_elements_by_link_text(po):
        print("FOUND!!!!", po, tracking)
```